# Symfony2 only use values from json_encode

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting some information from my database and holding that information in an array. I've used `{{dump(weights)}}` in my `twig` template, see below the dump of the array:

[image]

If i use `weights|json_encode()` I can get this information:

[image]

Which is okay, but my graph needs the data in a format like this - `[69,72]`.

For example, this is how the code should look for the graph:

```
var geckoWeight = {
  labels: dates,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Front",
      fillColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)",
      strokeColor: gradient,
      pointColor: gradient,
      pointStrokeColor: "#202b33",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(225,225,225,0.9)",
      data: [69,72]
    }
  ]
};
```

What is the best way to manipulate my data to suit what is needed in the graph data?

Comment: I'm using chart.js for this

Comment: Either use twig to transform the data, or do it in JS

Comment: @EJTH can you give any information on getting twig to transform it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (in a Model method or controller):

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function someAction()
    {
        $data = array(
            array('weight' => 69),
            array('weight' => 72),
        );

       $graphData = array_map(function($i) { return $i['weight']; }, $data);

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(           
            'data' => $weights,
        ));
    }
```

On my twig template:

```
<script>
    var weights = {{ data|json_encode }};
</script>
```

Comment: I think the way i'm doing it at the moment is the long way round of doing it. I will explore this option in a minute and let you know how i get on :)

Comment: I've tried this, however the dump just returns `[]`

Comment: Well, It works for me. What $graphData returns in your controller?

Comment: Nothing, it's just `[]`

Comment: hmm... So how your weight looks like? I think that's different that you have shown.

Comment: I've even used your hard coded array and it doesn't return anything in the dump. The code sample is in the first screenshot, that is the array i'm working with

Comment: So weird... Are you sure $weights is not a empty array? How about template, there is something like this: {{ weights|json_encode }} ?

Comment: Weight's definitely ins't empty, as if i use my original code the weights show like in my second screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79226/discussion-between-felipsmartins-and-andy-holmes).

Comment: You forgot a return statement in your array_filter closure

Comment: @Paziツ In fact, array_filter is not proper way to go.. because array_filter avaluate boolean expression results and retorn a previous value.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do that in the JS code:

```
var myWeights = {{ weights|json_encode() }};
var myWeightsArr = [];
for(var i in myWeights){
   if(myWeights.hasOwnProperty(i))
   myWeightsArr.push(myWeights[i].weight);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work if i set `data: myWeightsArr`

Comment: Can you get me the source of what is being output ?

Comment: It's just putting `69,72` which is kind of right, but as you can see in the code example, it needs to be `[69,72]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Your input data, something like this, should give You requested output

```
[
{% for weightsArray in weights %}
    {% if loop.index0 > 0 %},{% endif %}
    {% for weight in weightsArray %}
        {{ weight }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
]
```